# ¿Puedo usar dos url en una función ajax de jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function myFunction() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "../conexion/notificaciones.php",

              type: "POST",
              processData:false,
              success: function(data){
                $("#notification-count").remove();                  
                $("#notification-latest").show();$("#notification-latest").html(data);
              },
              error: function(){}           
            });
          }

          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').click(function(e){
              if ( e.target.id != 'notification-icon'){
                $("#notification-latest").hide();
              }
            });
          });                                     
        </script>
```

Comment: Hola Stiven , podría proporcionar un descripción del código ¿Qué intenta hacer? y donde presenta problemas o dificultades, para poder ayudarle.

Comment: no es que tenga problema solo tengo una duda, es que mi pregunta es si con esta funsion de ajax puedo añadirle otra url ejemplo notificaciones2.php o devo crear otra funsion para poner a funsionar notificaciones2.php?

Comment: entiendo que quieres ejecutar 2 ajax al mismo tiempo? o quieres usar otra url en lugar de la que ya tienes?

Comment: No, no puedes añadir otra url. Puedes ejecutar otro ajax dentro de algún evento de ese, pero no proporcionar dos urls y que se ejecuten ambas.

Comment: Fíjate en la [ayuda oficial](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) dice: 
**url**
Type: String
`A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.`